# Best way to call 32-bit unmanaged code from 64-bit Managed Code using a managed code wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, 32bit-64bit, managed

The frequency with which I am coming across the situation where I have to call native 32-bit code from a managed 64-bit process is increasing as 64-bit machines and applications become prevalent.  I don't want to mark my applciation as 32-bit and I cannot obtain 64-bit versions of of the code that is being calling.

The solution that I currently use is to create C++ COM shims that are loaded out of process to make the 32-bit calls from the 64-bit process.

This COM shim solution works well and the cross process calls are handled behind the scenes by COM, which minimises the overhead of this approach.

I would however like to keep all the new development that we undertake using C# and wondered if there are any frameworks that minimise the overhead of doing this.  I have looked at IPCChannel but I feel that this approach is not as neat as the COM shim solution.

thanks,
Ed

Comment: For what it is worth, the COM solution sounds like the way to go IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and my solution was to use [remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xws7132e.aspx). Basically the project consisted of:

- Platform-independent `CalculatorRemote.dll` library with

  - `CalculatorNative` internal static class with x32 P/Invoke methods
  - `RemoteCalculator` class derived from [`MarshalByRefObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx) which used native methods from `CalculatorNative`;
- Main platform-independent C# library (e.g. `Calculator.dll`), referencing `CalculatorRemote.dll`, with `Calculator` class which was privately using singleton of the `RemoteCalculator` class to invoke x32 functions where needed;
- x32 console application which hosted `RemoteCalculator` from `CalculatorRemote.dll` to consume by `Calculator.dll` via [`IpcChannel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel.aspx).

So if the main application started in x64 mode it was spawning a `RemoteCalculator` host application and used remoted `RemoteCalculator` instance. (When in x32 it just used a local instance of `RemoteCalculator`.) The tricky part was telling calculator-host application to shut down.

I think this it better than using COM because:

- You don't have to register COM classes anywhere;
- Interoperating with COM should be slower than .NET remoting;
- Sometimes if something is going wrong on the COM-side you need to restart your application to recover from that; (possibly I'm just not very familiar with COM)
- When running in x32 mode there won't be any performance penalty with remoting -- all methods will be invoked in the same AppDomain.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much the only answer is out of process communication.  You could create a .NET project that is a 32-bit executable that makes all of the 32-bit calls needed and communicate with it via Windows Messages, WCF, Named Pipes, Memory Mapped Files (4.0), etc.  I am pretty sure this is how Paint.NET does their WIA (Windows Imaging Acquisition) from a 64-bit process.

In the case of PDN, they simply pass the name of the file they expect as the output, but more complex communication isn't difficult.  It could be a better way to go depending on what you're doing.